# In Oracle, get max value while ignoring negative matching records

Tags: sql, oracle, max, negative-number

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
ID          Value

462338900   41040   
462338900   -41040  
462338900   50      
462338900   0
```

What I would like to do is get the max value from this table where the value field does not have a matching negative record. In the example above, 41040 would be the max value. However, since it has a negative matching record of -41040, I want to "throw it out" and bring back the new max value of 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upvoted Gordon's answer -- it's the right one.  However, depending on how big your table is and how many `ids` you're going after at one time, this could perform better, since it only reads the table once.  I.e., it doesn't require the ANTI JOIN operation that the `not exists` will require.

```
select id, max(value)  
from (
select id, abs(value) value, count(case when value < 0 then 1 else null end) neg_count
from t
group by id, abs(value) )
where neg_count = 0
group by id;
```

Also, be careful.. you stated your requirements very specifically.  If your data were

```
ID          Value
462338900   41040   
462338900   41040   
462338900   -41040  
462338900   50      
462338900   0
```

... with value 41040 duplicated, the single occurrence of -41040 would exclude both from the results at the max would be 50.  If you'd want the max to be 41040 in that case, it's a different query.  My version would be more adaptable to that requirement than the `not exists` approach: you could calculate a `pos_count` similar to `neg_count` and change `where neg_count=0` to `where pos_count > neg_count`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a method using `exists`:

```
select id, max(value)
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.value = - t.value
                 )
group by id;
```